# Prove that a function is differentiable everywhere

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $g$ be a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$. We know the following:

$g(0) = 0$

$g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g' (0) = c$

for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, g(x+y) = g(x) + 2xy + g(y).

I have to prove that $g$ is differentiable everywhere and find a formula for $g '$. I have tried using the formal definition of derivative by limit but I can't figure out where to begin with this. Could you help me out?

Comment: Just evaluate $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)} h.$$

Comment: how do I evaluate the above if I don't know what g(x) is?

Comment: Use what you know about $g$ ! The question is easy.

Comment: As @YvesDaoust pointed out, just try rewrite the numerator $g(x+h)-g(x)$ bearing in mind that $g(x+y)=g(x)+2xy+g(y)$

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: from $ g(x+h) = g(x) + 2xh + g(h)$ we get

$$\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h-0}=2x+\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{ h-0}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Following @Fred 's answer, I would just add that once we establish that $g'(x)= 2x + c$, we can even obtain the exact expression $g(x) = x^2 + cx$. This is not required as part of the answer but it is still nice that we can fully characterise such functions.